# autocomplete display employee name become hidden after 1 second or less why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I working on asp.net MVC project . I face issue after display Line Manager Name on autocomplete .

autocomplete functionality working success but issue happen after display data on input .

**Line Manager name hidden after 1 second or less so why this happen
this behavior happen on some computers and another not happen .**

Call `Web api` using `jquery Ajax` search for employee no like '%1234%' then display similar

result after select employee no it display Line Manager Name related on `LineManagerName`

but issue within 1 second or less After autocomplete display Line Manager Name become hidden

so why that happen

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"
            language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtLineManagerId").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var searchText = $("#txtLineManagerId").val();
                console.log("search text" + searchText)
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText", "Resignation")',
                    data: { searchText: searchText },
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                       
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.EmployeeID, value: item.EmployeeID, employeeName: item.EmployeeName };

                        }))

                    }
                });
            },
            position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom" },
            appendTo: '#searchContainer',
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#LineManagerName").val(ui.item.employeeName);
       
            },
            minLength: 4,
        });

 $("#txtLineManagerId").change(function () {
            var searchText = $("#txtLineManagerId").val();
            console.log("search text" + searchText)
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText", "Resignation")',
                data: { searchText: searchText},
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.EmployeeID, value: item.EmployeeID };
                    }))

                }
            });

 });
```

html controls using html helper

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LineManager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LineManager, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtLineManagerId" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LineManager, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.Label("Line Manager Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @*<input type="text" id="LineManagerName" class="form-control" />*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LineManagerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "LineManagerName" } })
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedEmployeeName" name="selectedEmployeeName">
               
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Explain Issue Sample Case**

Employee No on database Table employee have 3 employee `123456 123457 123458`

user add on input 1234 it display 3 employee `123456 123457 123458`

suppose user select 123456 then it display name related on Line Manager Name success

but after 1 second or less Line Manager Name become hidden so Why This Happen

And How to solve it

**updated post**

can you show me please How to use two events change and autocomplete without conflict each other

Are jquery and scripts attached suitable for  autocomplete or need updated
change event fire only one time

Comment: thanks for support can you show me please How to use two events without conflict each other

Comment: change event fire only one time